# Change the name of file in directory with csv extention

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I would like to change a file name with extension of csv into `test.txt`. The file is located in `/Users/xx/xx` . 
The problem is that, the name of the file is different every time (For example: `part-r-00000-865affea-3ead-445e-ad3e-8703a8d79026.csv`) and it is not predictable. However, the extension is always csv and the location also is constant.
I should mention that, the only file that exist in the folder each time is the mentioned csv file so, there is only one file in the folder that each time its name becomes different.
In fact, I need to change 
`part-r-00000-865affea-3ead-445e-ad3e-xxxx.csv` (the name always change) into `test.txt`

Can you help me?

Comment: will it always be with prefix `part-r`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it seems that. I generate this file with Spark.

Comment: `mv /path/to/*.csv /path/to/test.txt` (don't use this unless you're sure there is only a single `.csv` file in the directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use globbing to target a file without knowing its whole name.

Considering you know the file's directory, its extension, and that it is the only one with this extension in this directory, you can simply use this `mv` :

```
mv /Users/xx/xx/*.csv /Users/xx/xx/test.txt
```

This will rename every `.csv` file in `/Users/xx/xx/` (in your case, your single CSV file) into `/Users/xx/xx/test.txt`.

That would obviously be a problem if there was multiple `.csv` files since each would overwrite the previous one. If it could become a problem, you should either check the number of files which are matched by this glob and exit with error if it's greater than 1 or use a command that will only ever act on a single file.